# Prove $t_{n+1} = \frac{(A-1)t_n^2 + (A-2)\sqrt{A}t_n}{A(t_n + \sqrt{A})}$ converges for $A > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that the following sequence converges, given that $A$ is any real number greater than $1$:

$$t_1 = A-\sqrt{A}$$

$$t_{n+1} = \frac{(A-1)t_n^2 + (A-2)\sqrt{A}t_n}{A(t_n + \sqrt{A})}$$

Now, this sequence may look a little bit ridiculous, but notice that it if we could somehow change the $(A-2)$ factor to $(A-1)$, then this annoying expression would reduce to $\frac{A-1}{A}t_n$, which obviously converges to $0$.

My strategy has been to try to squeeze $t_n$ by showing that $|\frac{(A-1)t_n^2 + (A-2)\sqrt{A}t_n}{A(t_n + \sqrt{A})}| \leq\frac{A-1}{A}t_n$.  This inequality seems to hold for $A > \frac{3}{2}$, but not for $1<A<\frac{3}{2}$.

It also looks like we might be able to squeeze it underneath a different function, maybe something like $\frac{A^2}{n}$.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Assuming the sequence converges, can you compute the limit? It is the solution of a quadratic equation.